# ffmpeg encode stereo AAC

Tags: ffmpeg, aac

I'm trying to compress raw stereo audio into AAC with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f pulse 
  -ac 2 
  -b:a 128k 
  -acodec aac 
  -joint_stereo 1 
  -filter_complex ebur128=peak=true 
  -f flv rtmp://rtmp-server/stream
```

The ffmpeg output shows the bitrate is correct at 128kpbs

But the actual bandwidth used (measured with wireshark) is twice the bitrate and around 270kbps

is there any extra flag in ffmpeg?